# FBML dialog CSS

Tags: facebook, dialog, fbml

Before you say anything, yes I know FBML is horrible and deprecated, but currently we have not rewritten our app. It will be done though. At this time FBML custom dialogs have lost all our custom CSS in our app.

Is this a bug? Looking in Firebug it seems to no longer be under our app ID:

There is one div that is invisible, classed to `generic_dialog`, `pop_dialog`, and `app_content_(our-app-id)`

but the dialog that is showing is under the ID:

```
app_content_1319247071041 (not our app ID)
```

Is there any way to fix this, besides stopping to use `FBML`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a knew bug.
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/128905777213281

Personaly, I put my CSS in the HTML tags (style="") for this case. I agree, it's horrible, but it works ;)